# Ограничения на параметр шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, constraints

Есть шаблонный класс массива

```
template<class _Ty> class Array;
```

в котором реализована функция сортировки, которая требует наличия у параметра шаблона функции `CompareTo(_Ty& other);`
Так вот, как указать в определении шаблона что у параметра _Ty обязательно будет функция ComareTo(_Ty& other).
Что то подобное реализовано в C#, но не знаю как и возможно ли такое проделать на плюсах?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот мой вариант:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class has_CompareTo_self
{
    typedef char one[1];
    typedef char two[2];

    template <typename F, F> struct type_check;

    template <typename C> static one& test( type_check<int (C::*)(C&), &C::CompareTo>* );
    template <typename> static two& test(...);

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(one) };
};

template<class _Ty> class Array
{
    static_assert(has_CompareTo_self<_Ty>::value, "no appropriate CompareTo found");
};
```

Преимущество этого варианта в том, что он проверяет сигнатуры. То есть, принимает такой класс:

```
class Good
{
public:
    int CompareTo(Good& other);
};
```

но не такой:

```
class Bad
{
public:
    long CompareTo(Bad& other);
};
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/drYcz4

---

Давайте попробую объяснить, как эта шаблонная магия работает, чтобы мой вклад был больше, чем простая адаптация [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/264088/276994).

Главной идеей всех таких штук является принцип substitution failure is not an error ([SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)): если при разворачивании шаблона получается несколько перегрузок функции, но одна из них не компилируется, то это не ошибка, а просто молча игнорируется.

Сначала простое: `one` и `two` — две структуры данных гарантированно разного размера. Это нам понадобится в дальнейшем. Больше от этих структур ничего не требуется.

Теперь, центральный компонент кода — объявление

```
template <typename C> static one& test( type_check<int (C::*)(C&), &C::CompareTo>* );
```

Оно скомпилируется лишь если `type_check<int (C::*)(C&), &C::CompareTo>` имеет смысл. Для этого у класса `C` как минимум должен быть метод `CompareTo`.

Затем, у нас есть хитрый шаблон `type_check`, принимающий аргументами тип `F`, и *константное выражение* типа `F`! То есть для того, чтобы упоминание этого шаблона скомпилировалось, нужно, чтобы выражение, переданное ему вторым аргументом, имело такой тип, как в первом аргументе. В нашем случае это накладывает требование: `&C::CompareTo` должна иметь тип `int (C::*)(C&)` (то есть, функция-член, принимающая аргумент типа `C&` и возвращающая `int`).

Итак, это самое центральное объявление скомпилируется тогда и только тогда, когда у класса `C` есть функция-член `int C::CompareTo(C&)` — то, что нам и надо!

Как это работает дальше? У нас есть ещё одна перегрузка:

```
template <typename> static two& test(...);
```

которая компилируется всегда.

Посмотрим на строку

```
enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(one) };
```

Она объявляет внутренний `enum` с одним значением `value`. Правую часть (то есть, значение самого `value`) компилятор может вычислить, т. к. это константное выражение времени компиляции! Каков тип `test<T>(0)`? Если центральная строка скомпилировалась, то 0 подходит в качестве указателя на структуру `type_check<...>`, и тип возвращаемого значения — `one`. Если нет, то работает вторая перегрузка, и тип возвращаемого значения — `two`. Различить эти два случая помогает сравнение размеров: `sizeof(one)` не равен `sizeof(two)`. Таким образом, в зависимости от компилируемости центральной строки значение `value` — `true` или `false`.

Вся эта механика спрятана внутри шаблона `has_CompareTo_self`, чтобы не засорять нормальным людям область видимости.

Дальше всё просто: мы применяем `static_assert` в теле нашего шаблона `Array`. Конец!

---

Да, я тоже считаю, что это неподдерживаемый код, и что метапрограммирование должно иметь менее вырвиглазный синтаксис.

Comment: Спасибо.
Вроде немного разобрался.

Comment: @Артём: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

В C++11 можно сделать static_assert с std::is_base_of. Придется сделать базовый класс с методом ComareTo(_Ty& other); и проверять, является ли этот класс базовым классом для текущей спецификации шаблона.

Answer (score 2):

В определении шаблона - пока никак. В настоящий момент такой функциональности просто не существует. Она прорабатывается на уровне комитета, но не вошла в стандарт, пока.

Существуют методы, с помощью которых можно это сделать. Но они далеки от идеала и используют довольно зубодробительный код. Но это не самое страшное, самое страшное, что они не являются общими и для каждой функции нужно писать свой код. Можете посмотреть на английском SO [пример ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature) с таким кодом.

Comment: Видимо только так и придется.
На самом то деле я пишу таблицу в которой все данные при вставке будут сортироваться по некоторому ключу, для чего собственно и необходима функция сравнения и что бы можно было писать
`Table<int> t; t.Find(key);`

Comment: Проверка на наличие функции вовсе необязательна, т.к. если её нет, Вы всё равно получите ошибку. Правда не такую красивую, какую можно получить с помощью определения наличия функции и `static_assert`

Comment: Ну, не такой уж зубодробительный, SFINAE — стандарт в [TMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming).

Comment: @VladD, стандарт - да, но он от этого лучше не становится и те люди, кто мало занимался метапрограммированием шаблонов зачастую приходят в ужас от того, что видят. Да и те, кто много занимался, иногда имеют расширенные зрачки от увиденного.

Comment: @ixSci: Семантика-то там простая, смысл тривиален, но вот описывать это всё в терминах SFINAE и рекурсивных шаблонов совершенно ужасно. Написал бы кто-нибудь приличный метаязык.

Comment: @VladD, насколько я понимаю, в D много человеческого метапрагроммирования реализовано. Ну и C++ тоже идёт в правильно направление, как мне кажется. Concepts [Light] это довольно хорошая штука, которая позволит избавиться от многих сложных конструкций.

Comment: @ixSci: Ждём-с.

Answer (score 2):

Установить ограничение на параметр шаблона просто так (из вредности) нельзя. Но зато можно проверить наличие у параметра шаблона определённой функции и в случае отсутствия таковой переключиться на отдельную специализацию шаблона.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class ensure_CompareTo {
    // используем SFINAE, чтобы определить наличие функции
    // когда функция есть, выбирается первый шаблон, когда нет - второй
    template <typename U> static T test(char (*)[sizeof(&U::CompareTo)]);
    template <typename U> static void test(...);
public:
    // этот алиас зависит от того, какой шаблон был выбран с помощью SFINAE
    // он равен либо исходному типу, либо void
    using type = decltype(test<T>(0));
};

// базовый шаблон массива
// второй параметр выводится автоматически из первого
// он либо совпадает с ним, когда требуемая функция есть, либо равен void
template <typename T, typename TT = typename ensure_CompareTo<T>::type>
class Array {
public:
    static const char* desc() { return "отсортированный массив"; }
};

// специализация шаблона массива для случая, когда второй параметр, выводимый
// автоматически из первого, оказался равным void, т.е. когда требуемой
// функции в параметре шаблона не оказалось
template <typename T>
class Array<T, void> {
public:
    static const char* desc() { return "просто массив"; }
};

class A {
public:
    int CompareTo(A& other);
};

class B { };

int main()
{
    cout << Array<A>::desc() << endl;
    cout << Array<B>::desc() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Можно пожалуйста добавить комментариев к коду.

Comment: @АртёмКотелевич добавил

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что это возможно. Но почему обязательно привязывать интерфейс сравнения к шаблону класса? Почему бы не сделать это как в Java или C#? Там есть параметризованный интерфейс `Comparable` (`IComparable` для C#), который реализуют классы, которые должны иметь возможность сравнения с экземплярами других классов. Таким образом вы получите даже большую гибкость, обеспечив возможность сравнения одновременно с несколькими типами данных:

```
template <class T> class Comparable {
public:
    virtual bool CompareTo(T* other) = 0;
};

template <class T> class Array : Comparable<Array<T> >, Comparable<int> {
public:
    Array() {}

    bool CompareTo(Array<T>* other) {
        return false;
    }

    bool CompareTo(int* other) {
        return false;
    }
};

int main() {
    Array<int> a;
    Array<int> b;
    int c = 123;
    a.CompareTo(&b);
    a.CompareTo(&c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Немного не то. Тот `Array` что Вы написали не шаблонный. Проблема в том, что компилятор не может заранее знать что параметр шаблона будет наследовать интерфейс `IComparable` и соответственно нельзя будет написать `_Ty.CompareTo(other);`

Comment: @АртёмКотелевич, тут Вы заблуждаетесь - написать так можно. Не надо путать generics из C# с шабонами из C++. Шаблоны куда мощнее и позволяют куда больше.

Comment: @АртёмКотелевич, если вам принципиально, чтобы класс, с которым вы будете сравнивать, был параметризован, причём именно тем типом, которым был параметризован исходный класс, то пожалуйста, я поправил ответ. Обратите внимание на пробел в `Comparable<Array<T> >`, это не опечатка, без него не скомпилируется. Вообще, было бы неплохо, если бы вы подробнее описали задачу, для которой вам нужны подобные махинации с шаблонами, возможно, есть другой способ её решения.

Comment: Нужно сделать класс таблицу, в которой элементы всегда будут отсортированы по некоторому ключу и по нему можно будет проводить поиск. Может Вы что то придумаете. А то у меня опыт работы с шаблонами небольшой.

Comment: А как вы храните данные в вашей таблице? Ваш класс - вся таблица или одна запись в ней? Как храните данные записи - в каком-то массиве (если да, то как определяете тип данных?) или в виде полей структуры/класса? Может, вам стоит задать отдельный вопрос, в котором вы подробно опишете вашу задачу и ваш вариант её решения, тогда вам смогут посоветовать вариант, подходящий именно вам. Можете привести ссылку на этот вопрос, если считаете, что он обеспечивает необходимый контекст.

Answer (score 1):

Если мы хотим просто проверить наличие члена - достаточно его вызвать.

Мы не хотим выполнять этот код, соответственно мы будем вызывать его в контексте который не приводит к выполнению кода, а именно `sizeof`, `decltype` или `noexcept`.

Код, который будет выполняться, во всех случаях выглядит одинаково - создание объекта с помощью `std::declval<T>()` и вызов метода:

```
std::declval<T>().CompareTo(std::declval<T&>())
```

Если надо проверить несколько свойств, можно использовать оператор "запятая":

```
std::declval<T>().f(), std::declval<T>().g()
```

При использовании `decltype` мы получаем тип, и его можно использовать как дополнительный параметр шаблона:

```
template<class T,
         class=decltype(std::declval<T>().CompareTo(std::declval<T&>()))>
struct Array {};
```

Этому `decltype` можно сделать псевдоним (alias)

```
template<class T> using has_CompareTo = decltype(std::declval<T>().CompareTo(std::declval<T&>()));
template<class T, class=has_CompareTo<T>> struct Array {};
```

Для `sizeof` и `noexcept` мы тоже можем использовать параметр шаблона:

```
template<class T, int=sizeof(std::declval<T>().CompareTo(std::declval<T&>()), 0)>
struct Array {};
```

`, 0` на конце выражения нужно на случай если результат `CompareTo` имеет тип `void`.

Также мы можем написать это как член класса:

```
template<class T>
struct Array {
    enum { has_CompareTo = noexcept(std::declval<T>().CompareTo(std::declval<T&>()), 0) };
    // или
    using has_CompareTo = decltype(std::declval<T>().CompareTo(std::declval<T&>()));
};
```

Вариант с параметром шаблона интересен тем что он включает [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), но в данном случае оно не нужно.